# Composition of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

Prove that if two linear transformations of rank 1 $f,g$ have equal kernels and images, i.e. $\mbox{Ker}f=\mbox{Ker}g$, $\mbox{Im}f=\mbox{Im}g$ then $fg=gf$. 
Any help would be appreciated, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you mean $f=g$?

Comment: Sorry a typo, my fault.

Comment: Consider the induced map $\overline{f} : V/\ker(f) \to \mathbb{K}$

Comment: Do you at least see $fg(x)=gf(x)$ for some particular $x$, say $x\in ker(f)$???

Comment: even i don't know how does it help... :P It was my immediate observation after seeing this question.. That is why i have said it... Did you tried using "rank 1 nature of f"????

Comment: I cannot see it actually, no. if $0\in Kerf$ then it is trivially true, but why does it have to be in $Kerf$?

Comment: what do you mean by "if $0\in Ker(f)$".. It will always be in $Ker(f)$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mbox{Im}f\subset \mbox{Ker}f$ then $fg=gf=0$. Let $\mbox{Im}f=\langle a\rangle\not\subset \mbox{Ker}f$, then $V=\mbox{Im}f\oplus \mbox{Ker}f$ and $f(a)=\alpha a, g(a)=\beta a$  for some $\alpha, \beta$ from the field.

Every $x\in V$ has a form $x=\gamma a+n$ for some $n\in\mbox{Ker}f$. Hence $fg(x)=f(\beta\gamma a)=\alpha\beta\gamma a=gf(x)$.

Comment: simple and elegant  answer :)

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik: Thank you.

Comment: @VAL9000: You are welcome!

Comment: @VAL9000 : Do you see where did we used "rank of $f$ is $1$" and "rank of $g$ is $1$"